# How do I test for a difference in the standard deviations of two groups?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, variance, standard-deviation, group-differences

I have two groups and I want to know if there is a difference in standard deviation (or variance if it's easier) for each parameter.

Here is a table of descriptive statistics for my data:
[image]

After running a Shapiro-Wilk test for normality on all of the parameters, none of the data is normally distributed :(.

I do all of my analysis in R, so if you have an R solution that would be extra awesome.

If you need more information, please ask and I will edit this post to include it.

Bonus points for tips on how to interpret and report the results! :)

Comment: So you just want to test if the SDs for chemically bonded differ from permanent?

Comment: @gung yes, normally I'd consider an F test but I don't have normal data. I may be completely wrong in that F test relies on normality, I haven't done much with variances and standard deviations in the past.